# Header for list

Tags: python

Here is the start of my file:

```
print("Welcome to Ebs Corp.")
print('Please browse my shopping list\n')
with open('./Catalouge2.csv', 'r') as ebsfile:
    products = []
    for line in ebsfile:
        products.append(line.strip().split(','))
    for item in products:
    print('{} {} £{}'.format(item[0],item[1],item[2]))
```

My csv file is:

```
12345678,Blue-Eyes White Dragon,5.60
87654321,Dark Magician,3.20
24681012,Toon Blue-Eyes White Dragon,2.00
10357911,Toon Dark Magician,3.00
54626786,Duel Mat,4.30
85395634,Deck Box,2.50
78563412,Pot of Greed,10.50
```

I want it to be able to add a header for each items. For the numbers at the start I want it to have 'GTIN' then 'Description' and then 'Price' and I would like them to be in line. Thanks

I want it to look like

```
GTIN---------------Description-----------------Price
12345678-----------Blue-Eyes White Dragon------5.60
87654321-----------Dark Magician---------------3.20
```

Here is an example but without all the loops http://pastebin.com/7GepdJSu

Comment: Please provide example of desired output.

Comment: So you basically want `products` to be a `dict` instead of `list`?

Comment: Your last `print` line needs to be indented.

Comment: If you're not using [the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), then you're not parsing CSV. Please use the module. As for your question: Do you want to use the header in the CSV file? Or just ignore it?

Comment: `print('GTIN {} Description {} Price £{}'.format(item[0],item[1],item[2]))` ?

Comment: Do you create the csv file? Are you asking how to add the headers? Or will the file never have the headers and it's just when printing?

Comment: Barmar If I do that then it will loop it for every single line and thats not what I want

Comment: `I want it to look like` what is `it`? - a new csv, stdout?

Comment: I want it to look like that once its printed but with out the dashes. They will all be printed out all in a list like that

Comment: Look into python's `format()` function and [`formatting language`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#formatspec), e.g. `print('{:<10} {:^30} £{:>6}'.format(item[0],item[1],item[2]))`

Comment: I fyou use the Python format tubular, you could get http://pastebin.com/iXmtJH2L

Comment: neil It looks like its a lot of code and I was trying to keep it as small as possible?

Comment: Thanks, got it now. I am new to this but Is there now a way where I can delete this whole question? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). The formatting you need can be achieved using the built-in [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings). I am assuming you have a header row in your csv as follows

> GTIN,description,price

```
>>> import csv
>>> print_format = '| {0: <10} | {1: <30} | {2: >5} |'
>>> with open('/home/ashish/Desktop/sample.csv') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
...     print(print_format.format('GTIN', 'Description', 'Price'))
...     for row in reader:
...         print(print_format.format(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
... 
| GTIN       | Description                    | Price |
| GTIN       | description                    | price |
| 12345678   | Blue-Eyes White Dragon         |  5.60 |
| 87654321   | Dark Magician                  |  3.20 |
| 24681012   | Toon Blue-Eyes White Dragon    |  2.00 |
| 10357911   | Toon Dark Magician             |  3.00 |
| 54626786   | Duel Mat                       |  4.30 |
| 85395634   | Deck Box                       |  2.50 |
| 78563412   | Pot of Greed                   | 10.50 |
```

Comment: I dont have a header row in my csv file. I wanted to have it in python. Also I didnt want the dashes to be there

Comment: Kind of wanted it to look like this if it helps. http://pastebin.com/7GepdJSu

Comment: But without all the loops

Comment: @EbrahimMohammed I have updated the answer as per your pastebin format. Do read up on the links I have mentioned and make changes as per requirement.

Comment: Thanks, got it now. I am new to this but Is there now a way where I can delete this whole question? Thanks for your help

Comment: Why do you want to delete the question? Unless the question is offensive or spam, questions are usually not deleted.

Comment: I just don't really like the fact that I posted it. Is there a way?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63983/can-i-delete-my-own-question